# c++ Matrix with Expression template issues

Tags: c++, matrix, matrix-multiplication, expression-templates

I have to make a school project, which work with matrices. In Visual Studio 2010 everything works fine. The tester server have the "matrix_base" and the main function, for example:

```
template<class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp> class my_matrixAdd;
template<class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp> class my_matrixSub;
template<class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp> class my_matrixMul;

template<class T,  int N,  int M>
class my_matrix //: matrix_base
{
private:
    T arrData[N][M];
    int columns;
    int rows;
public:

    my_matrix() : columns(N), rows(M) {}
    template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
    my_matrix<T, N, M> & operator=(
        const my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> & mx)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
            {
                At(i, j) = mx.At(i, j);
            }
        return *this;
    }

    template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
    my_matrix<T, N, M> & operator=(
        const my_matrixMul<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> & mx)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
            {
                At(i, j) = mx.At(i, j);
            }
        return *this;
    }

    template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
    my_matrix<T, N, M> & operator=(
        const my_matrixSub<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> & mx)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<N; ++i)
            for(int j=0; j<M; ++j)
            {
                At(i, j) = mx.At(i, j);
            }
        return *this;
    }

    virtual ~my_matrix() {}
    const T& At(int n,  int m) const
    {
        return arrData[n][m];
    }
    T& At(int n,  int m)
    {
        return arrData[n][m];
    }

    const T& operator()(int n,  int m) const
    {
        return arrData[n][m];
    };

    T& operator()(int n,  int m)
    {
        return arrData[n][m];
    };


    int Columns() const { return columns; }
    int Rows()    const { return rows;    }

};

template< class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
class my_matrixAdd
{
private:
    const LeftOp& m_lhs;
    const RightOp& m_rhs;
public:
    my_matrixAdd(
        const LeftOp& lhs,  const RightOp& rhs) :
        m_lhs(lhs),  m_rhs(rhs) {}
    T At(int x,  int y) const
    {
        return m_lhs.At(x,  y) + m_rhs.At(x,  y);
    }
};


template<class T,  int N,  int M>
inline my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrix<T, N, M> , my_matrix<T, N, M>  >
operator+(const my_matrix<T, N, M>  &l,  const my_matrix<T, N, M>  &r)
{
    return my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrix<T, N, M> ,
           my_matrix<T, N, M>  > (l, r);
}

template<class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
inline my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> ,
       my_matrix<T, N, M>  >
       operator+(const my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp>  &l,
                 const my_matrix<T, N, M>  &r)
{
    return my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> ,
           my_matrix<T, N, M>  > (l, r);
}

template<class T,  int N,  int M,  class LeftOp,  class RightOp>
inline my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrixSub<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> ,
       my_matrix<T, N, M>  >
       operator+(const my_matrixSub<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp>  &l,
                 const my_matrix<T, N, M>  &r)
{
    return my_matrixAdd<T, N, M, my_matrixSub<T, N, M, LeftOp, RightOp> ,
           my_matrix<T, N, M>  > (l, r);
}

int main()
{
    my_matrix<int,2,2> mtx1;
    my_matrix<int,2,2> mtx2;
    my_matrix<int,2,2> mtx3;
    my_matrix<int,2,2> mtx4;
    mtx4 = mtx1 + mtx2 + mtx3;
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler in the server is a g++ with -static -O2 parameters.
And i get errors like:

> /var/www/F/I704e/3/1/teszt1.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
>
> /var/www/F/I704e/3/1/teszt1.cpp:42: error: no match for ‘operator+’ in ‘operator+(const my_matrix&, const my_matrixAdd&) [with T = int, int N = 5, int M = 3, LeftOp = my_matrix, RightOp = my_matrix](((const my_matrixAdd, my_matrix >&)((const my_matrixAdd, my_matrix >*)(& operator+(const my_matrix&, const my_matrix&) [with T = int, int N = 5, int M = 3](((const my_matrix&)((const my_matrix*)(& mtx3)))))))) + operator+(const my_matrixAdd&, const my_matrix&) [with T = int, int N = 5, int M = 3, LeftOp = my_matrix, RightOp = my_matrix](((const my_matrix&)((const my_matrix*)(& mtx6))))’

And like:

> In file included from /var/www/F/I704e/3/1/teszt1.cpp:6:
>
> /var/www/Hallg/I704e/3/h145172/7/feladat.cpp: In function ‘my_matrixAdd, my_matrixAdd > operator+(const my_matrixAdd&, const my_matrixAdd&) [with T = int, int N = 5, int M = 3, LeftOp = my_matrix, RightOp = my_matrix]’:

Please help me! Thank You!

Comment: Don't write unreadable code please, `typedef` is your friend.

Comment: Put compiler error messages in code blocks.  Minimize the amount of code in the line by doing one + per line to start.  Remove unnesseaary template parameters like N and M and replace them with constants.  Remove unnessesary classes like your mult and sub ones.  Make a minimal failing case, and don't spew code and expect people to was through it.

Comment: Irondically, after the my edit I made, the code compiles... just fine for me

Comment: Thank You! But still the same problem on the server.

Answer (score 0):

This is an extended comment.

Here is my stripping of all of the unrequired stuff in your question:

```
template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp> 
class my_matrixAdd;

struct matrix_base {};

class my_matrix : matrix_base
{
public:
        my_matrix() {}
        template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp> 
        my_matrix & operator=(const my_matrixAdd<LeftOp, RightOp> & mx) {
                return *this;
        }

        virtual ~my_matrix() {}
};

template< class LeftOp,  class RightOp> 
class my_matrixAdd
{
private:
        const LeftOp& m_lhs; 
        const RightOp& m_rhs; 
public:
        my_matrixAdd(const LeftOp& lhs,  const RightOp& rhs) : m_lhs(lhs),  m_rhs(rhs) {} 
};


inline my_matrixAdd<my_matrix , my_matrix  > 
operator+(const my_matrix  &l,  const my_matrix  &r) {
        return my_matrixAdd<my_matrix, my_matrix > (l, r);
}

template<class LeftOp,  class RightOp>  
inline my_matrixAdd<my_matrixAdd<LeftOp, RightOp> , my_matrix  > 
operator+(const my_matrixAdd<LeftOp, RightOp>  &l,  const my_matrix  &r) {
    return my_matrixAdd<my_matrixAdd<LeftOp, RightOp>, my_matrix>(l, r);
}
#include <utility>
int main() {
    my_matrix mtx1;
    my_matrix mtx2;
    my_matrix mtx3;
    my_matrix mtx4;

    // really, we should figure out what type these are explicitly, instead of using auto:
    auto&& tmp1 = mtx1 + mtx2;
    auto&& tmp2 = std::move(tmp1) + mtx3;
    mtx4 = std::move(tmp2);
    auto&& tmp3 = mtx2 + mtx3;
    auto&& tmp4 = mtx1 + std::move(tmp3);
    mtx4 = std::move(tmp4);

    return 0;
}
```

note that this version also fails to compile.  The reason is more obvious, however.

You should strip your code down to something like this, either ask for help understanding why there is still an error, fix it (or note that there is no longer a problem), then build it back up one step at a time.

You'll note that the classes don't do anything anymore -- which is good, because a type error isn't caused by what distant code does.  (at worst, it is caused by their signature, which I left unchanged).

Comment: Ok thx for the striping. Sorry I'm very tired, the project changed to this "testing & scorer server" few days ago. And i need finish this in time. I hope someone know the solution.

Comment: So, did you try compiling my simple version, and looking at the error produced?  On the online ideone compiler, it happened at this line: `auto&& tmp4 = mtx1 + std::move(tmp3);`, and the error message is pretty informative.  :)

Comment: You mean this: `c:\feladat>g++ fe.cpp -o fe -static -O2
fe.cpp: In function int main():
fe.cpp:47: parse error before &&
fe.cpp:49: tmp2 undeclared (first use this function)
fe.cpp:49: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
fe.cpp:49: for each function it appears in.)
fe.cpp:49: undeclared variable move (first use here)
fe.cpp:50: parse error before &&
fe.cpp:52: tmp4 undeclared (first use this function)`

Comment: Please tell me what to do with my error, on my compile server. Still doesn't see the operators...

Comment: Oh, you are not using a C++11 compiler.  You should mention the version of the compiler when running into compiler errors.  You have an operator matrix+matrix and add result+matrix but no operator matrix+add result.

Comment: Ok, i will try. Well i have to use the school's compiler in the server, and no idea which is. On my PC i have a new g++ and a VS 2010, but my code work on both without any problem. Dont forget i have a lot operator, just i didn't posted all. No one will read 300 lines of code. Let's see. Thanks again.